# document.getElementById innerHTML Not working in loop

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing, innerhtml, document.write

Hy ! I am trying to put the result of an XMLHttpRequest inside a div using document.getElementById innerHTML without success.

**In the head :**

```
XMLHttpRequest is fine (I tried document.write and it show my results).

Here is my code :

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.mywebsite.com/my.php",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

for(var i=0; i < xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("place").length; i++) {
name = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById('name').innerHTML += name +"<br>"; 
}
```

**In the body :**

```
<div id="name"></div>
```

***NB :***
my.php generate xml file and replacing the line document.getElementById... by document.write(name + "br tag"); is working fine.

**Thanks** in advance for help.

Comment: Can you post your xml response?

Comment: You shouldn't be continually appending to `innerHTML` in a loop (ie. appending to the DOM). Build the HTML contents in a variable and assign to `innerHTML` in one go at the end.

Comment: Here is part of of xml created : -<result>-<place><id>500</id><name>palazzo dei pio</name></place></result>

Comment: Thanks w3d I do not see how to do this. But my goal is to display picture, name, address for each record separated by new line (br) each new record;

Comment: Just a hunch... use a different variable other than `name` in `name = xmlDoc.etc` eg. `xmlName`. You appear to be referencing `name` in the global scope? (Where is this defined with `var`?) If you are referencing a global `name` then you might be removing your `id="name"` element from the DOM?! Is `document.getElementById('name')` returning a valid element?

Comment: Thanks. I will try and post later cause I am out right now. Nb. It works with document.write.

Comment: Yes, it works with `document.write` because you aren't assigning to the `name` element (as mentioned in my comment, this might be getting overwritten). Also, check the console for any errors.

Comment: ok back and I changed as your suggestions w3d. console log me : TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null and no valid element returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found my mistakes and here is the working code :

```
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
else{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
    for(var i=0; i < xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("place").length; i++) {
        var xmlName = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML += xmlName +"<br>"
    }
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://mywebsite.com/xmlcreate.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Thanks for helps !